# PHP execution terminating early when accessing via browser

Tags: php, goutte

I'm trying to get my head around PHP and am setting a little script up on Apache/Linux.

If I call this as `php index.php` from the shell it executes fine. But if I call the same via my browser, it fails to execute. There is no info in the apache error log.

What can be the cause for this?

The script is scraping another getting a url via `Goutte` and `curl`, so takes about 3 seconds to execute.

-- To respond to comments --

I was omitting the code as it's trivial, a Goutte client, a single request followed by extracting the `h1` tag.

It's working in the console but calling via Chrome tells me I am missing curl - which is install with `apt-get install php-curl`

Comment: And where should we help? Should we fix the invisible code?

Comment: Have you confirmed that PHP is enabled for your Apache server in the httpd.conf or by loading a page with `phpinfo();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, show php errors... paste this at the very top of your page

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Then view it, you should see a list of errors/warnings depending on the situation. Otherwise will need to see some of your code to know what your dealing with.

If that fails and still gives you nothing/blank page.. Be sure a very basic php script works on your server through the web browser.

```
<?php
  echo 'Hello World From PHP';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Having done that I can see that the error messages return that I am missing curl. Which is odd as it is installed and used when calling this locally on the server.

Comment: Make sure extension=php_curl.dll is enabled

Comment: Being i dont use CLI/CGI much, but in general gonna guess that is disabled , has a semicolon in front in the config file.. But as for it working on CLI, not sure there.

Comment: in general, a google of enabling curl for php should return a result

Comment: Thanks mayhem. I found the issue. I had installed php5-curl, but not restarted apache since.

Comment: hopefully the world is a rosie place again

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the cause. I had not restarted apache after installing php5-curl.